# ng build generating different outputs

Tags: angular, angular-cli

All,

I need to deploy two angular project.  Both builds fine locally and displays the index page.  When I deploy to kubernetes, one application complains that it can't find runtime.js, polyfills.js, styles.js, vendor.js and main.js, while the other application works fine.

I looked into the /dist folder of both application.  The application that works has the following in /dist folder.
`main.js polyfills.js runtime.js scripts.js vendor.js`

Application that fails has the following files

`main-es2015.js main-es5.js polyfills-es2015.js polyfills-es5.js runtime-es2015.js runtime-es5.js styles-es2015.js styles-es5.js vendor-es2015.js vendor-es5.js`

I have couple of questions

1. Why ng build generated different file.  I read number of posts.  It seems ng build --watch generated different files compared to ng build.  But I am not using ng build --watch.
2. Why my application with es5 and es2015 worked locally but when deployed to kubernetes failed?

I am using following angular version

Angular CLI: 11.1.4
Node: 12.22.1

Any clue will be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need a `serve-path`.
If this is not provided, the application will look to the root of your application.

f.e.

- `my.website.com/test` needs the `--serve-path=test`
- `my.website.com` don't need a `serve-path`

More information can be found on https://angular.io/cli/serve

Answer (score 1):

In the project creating the -2015, -es5 bundle files you're invoking [differential loading](https://angular.io/guide/deployment) meaning that in the browserslist file you're likely supporting an older browser, and in your tsconfig.json file in the `compilerOptions` your `target` is probably es2015 (aka es6) but the compiler thinks it needs to support older es5 browsers like IE. So it generates bundles accordingly to support both es2015 (aka es6) as well as es5.

As for the specifics of your deployment issues, well would probably need more details in your process there but hope this helps. Cheers

Comment: You are correct.  My .browserslistrc has the following content
```
> 0.5%
last 2 versions
Firefox ESR
not dead
not IE 9-11 # For IE 9-11 support, remove 'not'.
```

Updating the file resolved the issue